# Pandas: count how many rows between two values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Let say I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Est': [1.18,1.83,2.08,2.30,2.45,3.21,3.26,3.54,3.87,4.58,4.59,4.98],
'Buy': [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
})


    Est     Buy
0   1.18    0
1   1.83    1
2   2.08    1
3   2.30    1
4   2.45    0
5   3.21    1
6   3.26    1
7   3.54    0
8   3.87    1
9   4.58    0
10  4.59    0
11  4.98    1
```

I will like to create a new dataframe with two columns and 4 rows with the following format: the first row contains how many 'Est' values are between 1 and 2, and how many 1's in the column 'Buy'; the second row the same for the 'Est' values between 2 and 3; third row between 3 and 4, and so on. So my output should be

```
    A   B
0   2   1
1   3   2
2   4   3
3   3   1
```

I tried to use the *where* clause in pandas (or np.where) to create new columns with restrictions like `df['Est'] >= 1 & df['Est'] <= 2` and then count. But, is there an easier and cleaner way to do this? Thanks

Comment: i dont understand your rules for collapsing this ... could you try explaining in a different way ?

Comment: Show how you implemented this please

Comment: @JoranBeasley my 'Est' column has decimal numbers between 1 and 5. I just want to count how many of those values lie within the intervals [1,2), [2,3), [3,4), [4,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to group by the floor of the first column:

```
g = df.groupby(df['Est'] // 1)
```

You count the `Est` column:

```
count = g['Est'].count()
```

And sum the `Buy` column:

```
buys = g['Buy'].sum()
```